# Using $\leq$ as <

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Since $\le$ means less than or equal to. Can we use it when just one condition (less than) satisfies?

For example if $a + b \le 1$

can we say $a + b\leq 2$

instead of writing $a + b < 2?$

Comment: Yes. However $a+b<2$ gives more information.

Comment: Since $1<2\le 2$ we have $a+b\le 1\implies a+b<2\implies a+b\le 2.$

Comment: Yes, as long as it holds by transitivity of $a+b\leq 1\leq 2$

Comment: @JohnGriffin But doesn’t second equation add an extra info that $a+b$ may be equal to 2?

Comment: $a+b \le 1$ and $a+b < 2$ are equivalent if $a,b$ are *integers,* but not for real numbers.

Comment: @piepi It adds extra possibilities, which limits how much information is provided. If I see a man with black hair, it is more informative to describe him as a "man with black hair" as opposed to "a man with dark hair".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  $a+b \le 1$ is true then $a+b \le 2$ is also true.

But the assertion $a'+b' \le 2$ is weaker than the assertion $a'+b' < 2$. 
For example if $a'=b'=1$ then the former is true while the latter is not.

Generally, asserting an inequality does not imply that the inequality is best possible. It is true that $12 \le 15$. It is also true that $12 \le 14$ and even that $12 < 14$.

But additionally note that while **for  the integers** the inequalities $a+b \le 1$ and $a+b < 2$ are equivalent (one is true exactly when the other is true), this is no longer the case for the inequalities $a+b \le 1$ and $a+b \le 2$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at the end. When is it no longer the case?

Comment: @lakada The inequalities $a+b\le 1$ and $a+b\le 2$ are not equivalent even when $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be integers.